# list inspect second item print first item in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to dissect items from a list (from a file)

```
file data with name, number of goals, passes.
Luis,8,3
Montes and Kyle,10,8
Sharon, 22, 4
Nayum,3,8
```

So far:

```
filen=open("WorldData.txt", 'r')

values = []##List
for line in open(filen):
    values.append(line.rstrip('\n').split(','))

xl=values

numlist=[]
for line in xl:
    numlist.append(int(line[1]))#second element which are goals

x=(max(numlist))
print(x)

filen.close()
```

Which would give out: 22 but I'm also trying to find the name of the person who won.
I tried indexing so I could find the number of the line where the value is [::] so I could then print the first element...

```
print(xl.index(str(x)))
```

but it says

```
ValueError: '22' is not in the list
```

So I can't even get there.

How can I find who made the most goals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use numlist as dictionary. . so the code would be something like

```
goals = 0

numlist={}
for line in xl:
    numlist[line[0]]=int(line[1])#second element witch are goals

for player in numlist:
    if numlist[player] > goals:
        winner = player
        goals = numlist[player]
print goals, winner
```

answer printed would be 22 Sharon. would have take care of duplicates though or tie amongst multiple winner. for that you can maintain a list for winner and append it .

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would read the csv data:

```
import csv

data={}
with open(fn, 'r') as fin:
    reader=csv.reader(fin)
    header=next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        data[row[0]]=list(map(int, row[1:]))
print(data)
# {'Luis': [8, 3], 'Nayum': [3, 8], 'Montes and Kyle': [10, 8], 'Sharon': [22, 4]}
```

You can see now that you have a [dict](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) of [lists](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

Now just find the entry that has the max value for the value `number of goals` which is the first element in each list. You can use the built-in [max](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) with a key function to see who won:

```
print(max(data.items(), key=lambda t: t[1][0]))
# ('Sharon', [22, 4])
```